# Mysql: What is the best way to get last inserted value of a field with condition

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to get last inserted value of a field with condition.Below is my code.is it ok?

```
SELECT c.field_chapter_value
FROM content_type_story c
INNER JOIN term_node t
WHERE t.tid = ? 
AND c.nid=t.nid
ORDER BY c.field_chapter_value DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: How are we supposed to tell? You give almost no info at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine join and where; use an ON clause:

```
SELECT c.field_chapter_value
FROM content_type_story c
INNER JOIN term_node t ON c.nid = t.nid
WHERE t.tid = ? 
ORDER BY c.field_chapter_value DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may ORDER BY DESC this column, based on the assumption that newer records got higher id (with the JOIN fix, as Bohemian suggested).

```
SELECT c.field_chapter_value
FROM content_type_story c
INNER JOIN term_node t ON c.nid = t.nid
ORDER BY t.tid DESC, c.field_chapter_value DESC
LIMIT 1
```